# I'm trying to check dates between an array, but returns me a empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<button
            onClick={() =>
              console.log(
                data.filter(
                  (element: apiData) =>
                    new Date(element.dataemissao) >= allDatesRange[0] &&
                    new Date(element.dataemissao) <= allDatesRange[length - 1],
                ),
              )
            }
          >
            data filteres
          </button>
```

It's working when I try get just dates that are bigger than the first value of `allDatesRange` array.

Comment: Can you try logging `allDatesRange` and make sure that the last date is greater than the first date? If the resulting array is empty it just means your filter condition isnt passing on any of the items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<button
        onClick={() =>
          console.log(
            data.filter(
              (element: apiData) =>
                new Date(element.dataemissao) >= allDatesRange[0] &&
                new Date(element.dataemissao) <= allDatesRange[allDatesRange.length - 1],
            ),
          )
        }
      >
        data filteres
      </button>
```